# Trying to get json data if the data name matches product attribute with php

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get data from a json file to be loaded into my wordpress site. I would like to get the price from the matching name of the product of the site that I crawled. I need the name of the product to match the product attribute I added into the product page on wordpress then to get the price if the name matches the attribute I added. I don't know if I am making sense, but here is my code so far. It partially worked, but it did the same price across all my products. I am newer to php so can someone assist?

```
    <?php

$str = file_get_contents('/run_results_apmex.json');

// decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// get the data
$coinPrice = $json['coin'][1]['price'];

// echo it
if($json['name'] == $product->get_attribute[ 'Apmex Vendor Name' ]){
echo $coinPrice;
}
else{
echo 'No results found';
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you provide what will be value of $product->get_attribute[ 'Apmex Vendor Name' ] ?

Comment: So the attribute is called 'Apmex Vendor Name' and the Value is the title of the product: '1 oz Gold American Eagle BU (Random Year)'. The reason I have it that way is because I crawled all products on their site, and I have to match their naming convention on my site. But I also have multiple vendors that I am crawling so I decided to add their naming conventions into my product as product attributes. Does that make sense?

Comment: But  '1 oz Gold American Eagle BU (Random Year)' is not available in the json/crawled data.

Comment: It is, here is the full link to that file: http://gold.explorethatstore.com/wp-content/themes/divi-ETS-child-theme/run_results_apmex.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the json array to check the product attribute and get the price.

```
$str = file_get_contents('/run_results_apmex.json');

// decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// default value
$coinPrice = "No results found";
$product_attribute = '1 oz Gold American Eagle BU (Random Year)';
// loop the json array
foreach($json['coin'] as $value){
    // check the condition
    if($value['name'] == trim($product_attribute)){ 
        $coinPrice = $value['price']; // get the price 
        break; // exit the loop
    }
}

echo $coinPrice;
```

Or you can create a recursive function to check the in_array

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://gold.explorethatstore.com/wp-content/themes/divi-ETS-child-theme/run_results_apmex.json');

// decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// here I am passing the string instead of $product->get_attribute[ 'Apmex Vendor Name' ]. replace it in your code
$product_attribute = '1 oz Gold American Eagle BU (Random Year)';
$coinPrice = ($check = in_array_recursive(trim($product_attribute), $json['coin'])) ? $check['price']: 'No results found';
echo $coinPrice;
// output is $1,426.19

function in_array_recursive($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_recursive($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!! Hmm that seemed to not find the coin price, could it be because it is not reading the attribute?

Comment: May be, can you try placing '1 oz Gold American Eagle BU (Random Year)' instead of $product->get_attribute[ 'Apmex Vendor Name' ]

Comment: I would do that, but I need this to work for multiple products in a couple of different json files. So I am adding that naming convention into the wordpress product dashboard as attributes. That way we can add more products in, and have it work. Is it possible I have the wrong call for the attribute?

Comment: Yes, there is a possibility that the attributes are not fetched correclty. First check if your code is getting correct attribute. $product->get_attribute[] should be a valid data

Comment: Yes that is the correct attribute name, and the value is correct as well

Comment: If so, can you check if your json array is not empty. print_r($json);

Comment: Ok I did the print, and the array came back with the data in it.

Comment: can you check manually if the product attribute is in json array ?

Comment: I did the value of the attribute is 1 oz Gold American Eagle BU (Random Year) and a name in the json file is  the same. The price on that product is $1,321.09. Do I need to have the attribute value in quotes or anything like that?

Comment: No need. trim the attribute value for white spaces in the condition. trim($product->get_attribute[ 'Apmex Vendor Name' ]). I tested and got the price $1,321.09

Comment: So I did that as well when you showed the defined attribute, and that does work, but I need to ensure that I can call the attribute value as that information will be entered per product in the wordpress dashboard

Comment: Yup for whatever reason I cannot get the function to work with the attribute call. I have tried a bunch of different ways to call the attribute and none of them seem to work.

Comment: If you have any other advice to make this work. I would greatly appreciate it!